# How to update a dictionary with a user's input

Tags: python, dictionary, user-input

I'm trying to take information from the user and then take that info to update a dictionary. It's a part of an exercise I'm doing. I've tried to use .format(var1, var2) with the way you update a dictionary, but when ends up happening is only one part of the dictionary gets updated.

```
name_grade = {}

while True:

    name = raw_input("Please give me the name of the student [q to quit]:")
    if name == 'q':
        break
    else:
        grade = raw_input("Give me their grade: ")
        name_grade['{}'] = '{}'.format(name, grade)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
name_grades = {}

while True:
    name = input("Please give me the name of the student [q to quit]:")
    if name == 'q':
        break
    else:
        grade = input("Give me their grade: ")
        name_grades[name]=grade
print(name_grades)
```

Are you looking for this or something else?

Answer (score 1):

You can update the dictionary by saying

```
name_grade[name] = grade
```

Comment: Wow, this is the first time I've posted a question and you guys answer so fast. It worked thanks!